# sql join syntax

Tags: sql, syntax, join

I'm kind of new to writing sql and I have a question about joins.  Here's an example select:

```
select bb.name from big_box bb, middle_box mb, little_box lb
where lb.color = 'green' and lb.parent_box = mb and mb.parent_box = bb;
```

So let's say that I'm looking for the names of all the big boxes that have nested somewhere inside them a little box that's green.  If I understand correctly, the above syntax is another way of getting the same results that we could get by using the 'join' keyword.

Questions: is the above select statement efficient for the task it's doing?  If not, what is a better way to do it?  Is the statement syntactic sugar for a join or is it actually doing something else?

If you have links to any good material on the subject I'd gladly read it, but since I don't know exactly what this technique is called I'm having trouble googling it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using implicit join syntax. This is equivalent to using the JOIN keyword but it is a good idea to avoid this syntax completely and instead use explicit joins:

```
SELECT bb.name
FROM big_box bb
JOIN middle_box mb ON mb.parent_box = bb.id
JOIN little_box lb ON lb.parent_box = mb.id
WHERE lb.color = 'green'
```

You were also missing the column name in the join condition. I have guessed that the column is called `id`.

This type of query should be efficient if the tables are indexed correctly. In particular there should be foreign key constraints on the join conditions and an index on `little_box.color`.

An issue with your query is that if there are multiple green boxes inside a single box you will get duplicate rows returned. These duplicates can be removed by addding DISTINCT after SELECT.

Comment: The "implicit" syntax is ANSI-89; the "explicit" is ANSI-92

Comment: Thorough answer, thanks for the tips.  That was sloppy to leave off the bb.id (or something).  Ok follow-up question: can I specify conditions from any of the tables in the where clause?  ie: WHERE lb.color = 'green' and mb.color = 'red'

Comment: Also, googling for the implicit join, there are some observations that implicit join is "old and outdated'.  Is that a consensus opinion among the wise?

Comment: @Nathan Spears: Most people prefer the explicit syntax. See for example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-versus-where-clause-any-difference

Comment: Thx!  Not to be a nag but you missed my first question.

Comment: @Nathan Spears: Is your first question *is the above select statement efficient for the task it's doing?*. My answer is *This type of query should be efficient if the tables are indexed correctly.* Depending on the distribution of your data there might be better ways to do it, but it's certainly a good start and should perform well in most situations.

Comment: I meant my first question in the comments: can I specify conditions from any of the tables in the where clause (of the select you suggested)? ie: WHERE lb.color = 'green' and mb.color = 'red'