# Sql - the multi-part identifier cannot be bound

Tags: sql, ident

```
select distinct 
   page0.MatterType, 
   page0.Name, 
   page0.MatterNo, 
   page0.security, 
   page0.serial,      
   page6.TribCaseNo, 
   contact0.Name as Cname
from 
   page0, page6, page14
left join 
   contact0 on page0.PrimaryContact = contact0.linkserial
where 
  page0.serial = page6.CaseSerial 
AND page0.serial = page14.CaseSerial 
AND (page14.staffmember = '100001^24' and page14.status != 'Inactive') 
AND page0.status != 'Closed'
```

I keep getting an error that

> the multi-part identifier page0.PrimaryContact could not be bound.

I've checked the syntax and the spelling and both seem to be correct.

Thanks!

Comment: does the PrimaryContact columns exist on the the page0 table?

Comment: Is there actually a column `page0.PrimaryContact`? I guess I'd verify that before the spelling.

Comment: Is there a PrimaryContact column on page0?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I double-checked this column does exist.

Comment: A note on your JOIN syntax. You're using a combination of implicit and explicit syntax which could get you into trouble. You should use explicit JOIN syntax only. See this post for why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731952

Comment: cant you remove the join and do from  page0, page6, page14, contact0 and add "AND page0.PrimaryContact = contact0.linkserial" to your where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your query work by changing the order of tables in `FROM` :

```
select distinct   
page0.MatterType,   
page0.Name,   
page0.MatterNo,   
page0.security,   
page0.serial,        
page6.TribCaseNo,   
contact0.Name as Cname  
from   
 page6, page14, page0 --NOTE: page0 is now  closest to join!!!
left join   
contact0 on page0.PrimaryContact = contact0.linkserial  
where   
page0.serial = page6.CaseSerial   
AND page0.serial = page14.CaseSerial   
AND (page14.staffmember = '100001^24' and page14.status != 'Inactive')   
AND page0.status != 'Closed'
```

**Update**.
 In general, I strongly encourage you not to mix old and new syntax (as it's done here),**p.campbell**'s solution is the right way to write queries.

Comment: Perfect.  That worked.  I actually didn't know that was old & new syntax.  Interesting.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to make explicit joins. Currently you're using the old join syntax. Consider refactoring:

```
select P0.*, P6.TribCaseNo, C0.Name as Cname
FROM        page0 AS P0
INNER JOIN  page6 AS P6 on P0.serial = P6.CaseSerial 
INNER JOIN  page14 AS P14 ON P0.serial = P14.CaseSerial
LEFT JOIN   contact0 AS C0 on P0.PrimaryContact = C0.linkserial

WHERE (P14.staffmember = '100001^24' AND P14.status != 'Inactive') 
AND   P0.status != 'Closed'
```

Comment: When I do that, I get more "the multi-part identifier could not be bound" for fields page0.name, page0.matterno, page0.security, page0.serial, page6.tribcaseno, and contact0.name.

Comment: @Terri Then your tables/views don't actually contain those columns. Edit your question to contain the CREATE scripts for all these tables, or perhaps a screenshot of those tables and all their column names.

Comment: SQL Server is telling you that they DON'T, as written. Perhaps change to this updated SELECT list. Edited my answer.

Comment: Is there some way to add a screen shot?  Any idea why SQL Server would think they don't exist?

Comment: Page0  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PAGE0](
 [SERIAL] [int] NOT NULL,
 [TYPELAW] [int] NULL,
 [SECURITY] [int] NULL,
 [Status] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [LINKSERIAL] [varchar](21) NULL,
 [division] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [MatterType] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [Name] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [DateClosed] [datetime] NULL,
 [MatterNo] [varchar](16) NULL,
 [PrimaryContact] [varchar](21) NULL,
 [DEFLD] [datetime] NULL,
 [abfld] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [lafld] [datetime] NULL,
 [OpenBy] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [TEXT2] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__PAGE0__6B24EA82] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

Comment: Page 6    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PAGE6](
 [Serial] [int] NOT NULL,
 [CaseSerial] [int] NOT NULL,
 [LinkSerial] [varchar](21) NULL,
 [TribType] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [Trib] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [TribVenue] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [TribCaseNo] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [Judge] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [ShortCaption] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [Plaintiff] [text] NULL,
 [CurrentVenue] [varchar](1) NULL,
 [Trib_]  AS ([Trib]),
 [NoShow] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [division] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [FilingDate] [datetime] NULL,
 [defendants] [varchar](500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__PAGE6__1A00E0922BABE5F0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to add images since I am a new user. (spam prevention)

Comment: @TerriDeweyTindle you can edit your question and post your create table scripts.