# How can I query a db using linq to get related rows with a single call?

Tags: c#, linq

Here's a very simple db schema to illustrate my question :

There are 3 tables. T1, T2 and T3.

T1 has one to many relationship with T2.

And T2 has one to many relationship with T3.

How can I get all rows in T3 that are related to T1.Id (primary key in T1) ?

Comment: Have you looked into [using a JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731952/sql-join-syntax)?  Please post what you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var t3Rows = dataContext.T3.Where(x => x.T2.T1.Id == id);
```